# Installed Precision drivers for Synaptics Touchpad: Mouse is moving but not clicking after using a while

Tags: drivers, touchpad, windows-10-v1809

I've installed the Precision touchpad drivers for my Synaptics in HP Laptop. All works great but after a while, it doesn't click anything. It just loses the ability of click, even though mouse cursor moves. I'm on Windows 10 October Update. I've tried all the drivers from Reddit/HowToGeek etc. All giving me the same results. What is the latest driver package available now and any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you narrowed it down to driver vs. touchpad by reloading the old driver or testing a different touchpad?

Comment: Yes tested different versions of precision drivers and all same.

Comment: 1. The only drivers to try are ones from HP or ones directly from Synaptics.  There is no reason to install anything from a third party, and those results may not be reliable.  If you are only testing third party drivers, you may not have a problem other than those drivers.  2. The timing still isn't clear.  Why did you install drivers at all besides what was provided with the laptop?  It sounds like it was working properly until the Windows update.  If so, reinstalling the original driver should fix it if it is a driver problem.  (cont'd)

Comment: 3. If it isn't a driver problem, the touchpad switches may be starting to go bad or have accumulated some dirt  or some liquid may have spilled there.